# NODE.js Lambda dynamodb documentClient get - returned data is not in [] JSON format. How to return a full JSON document datatype form GET

Tags: node.js, json, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda

I'm new to Node.js/AWS lambda. Ive successfully created several documentClient QUERY functions that return a single or multiple item JSON Document in this format:

[
{
"name": "andy",
"color": "purple",
"snack": "oreos"
}
]

When I use documentClient GET and get back my single record its in THIS format, which is not playing well with the client code (apple / ios swift)

{
"name": "andy",
"color": "purple",
"snack": "oreos"
}

I'm hopign i can change the format returned from documentClient.get() to include the fill JSON document format including leading and trailing brackets .. []

I am a node.js & aws.lambda and documentClient novice, so apologies if this is a very basic question....

provided in above text

Comment: You could start by actually showing some code of what you are doing

Comment: Why is your client expecting an array in response to fetching a single item? That seems problematic. However, if you must do this then simply return an array containing the single item from DynamoDB e.g. `JSON.stringify([item])`

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood well, you're receiving an object instead of a array.
You can use the scan function to retrieve an array of results:

```
var params = {
  TableName : 'Table',
  FilterExpression : 'Year = :this_year',
  ExpressionAttributeValues : {':this_year' : 2015}
};

var documentClient = new AWS.DynamoDB.DocumentClient();

documentClient.scan(params, function(err, data) {
   if (err) console.log(err);
   else console.log(data);
});
```

Or you can transform the result to array:

```
const document = await documentClient.get({
  TableName: "table-of-example",
  Key: {
    id: "id-of-example"
  }
});

return [data]
```

Please read the document to understand more how the document dynamodb sdk works: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSJavaScriptSDK/latest/AWS/DynamoDB/DocumentClient.html#scan-property

Comment: Success, thank you. I have been a developer and worked in technology since 1980 lol and this is one of the first times ive used a website like this. I appreciate the help!

Comment: It’s a pleasure to help you. Please mark as answered my answer and up vote if I helped you as you expect.